# ¿Por qué me cambia la ruta cuando ejecuto programas?

Tags: cmd, windows7

Ejecutando un programa llamado `com2exe.exe` desde la terminal se me ha acortado la ruta:

De:

`C:\Users\ByRussX\Downloads\`

Me ha cambiado a:

`C:\Users\ByRussX\DOWNLO~1\`

Tal como está escrito.

¿Alguen sabe a que se puede deber?

P.D: Mi OS es Windows 7 de 32 bits

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Claro. Es un programa antiguo, no compatible con las rutas *extendidas* de Windows95 y superior. Se activa la *capa de compatibilidad*, que asocia rutas de MS-DOS 8+3 (8 caracteres del nombre + 3 de la extensión) a las rutas completas.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias ;)

Comment: Eso debería ser una respuesta porque es La respuesta. :)